# PAN card number validation with the following criteria

Tags: java, c, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

Given a paragraph P of words which contain some PAN card Numbers. Count the number of distinct valid PAN card numbers in P.

A valid PAN card number is a 10 length alphanumeric word of the form: "AAAAA1111A"

1. A denotes any letter of English uppercase alphabet.
2. 1 denotes any digit in 0,1,2.....9.
3. The fourth character can be only from the set {"A","B","C","F","G","H","L","J","P","T","K"}.
4. The fifth character must be same as the first character.

Input

`$MKOFM53365d*02Hd|  ^BAAAB0000CAAC1111...%G`

Output

`2`

Can someone please point me to the correct solution, I tried the other solution on stackoverflow but it assumes that the user enter only the PAN card and not random characters.

For complete problem reference : https://justpaste.it/2ybbe

Answer (score 0):

Hope this piece of code will help you . Here the paragraph is split into words based on occurrence of the special character and kept it as a separate array.Rules 1 to 4 are applied.

```
        String paragraph = "$MKOFM53365d*02Hd|  ^BAAAB0000CAAC1111...%G";
        String[] words= paragraph.split("[\\[\\]\\\\;\\'=./{}|:\"<>?`~!@#$%^&*()_+-]");
        String FIXED_PAN_CHARACTERS = "ABCFGHLJPTK";
        int PAN_COUNT = 0;
        for (String word : words) {
            String trim = StringUtils.trim(word);
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(trim) || trim.length() < 10 || (trim.charAt(0) != trim.charAt(4))
                    || (FIXED_PAN_CHARACTERS.indexOf(trim.charAt(3)) == -1))
                continue;
            PAN_COUNT++;
        }
```